# AngularJS: using jsonplaceholder.typicode.com as a data source does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS so I got stuck with this small *Users* application.

Instead of writing the users array of data inside the controller - like I have already done [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/34749/) (jsFiddle), sucessfully - I want to use jsonplaceholder.typicode.com as a data source:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module

app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.users = root + "/users";

}]);
```

```css
.search-box {
  margin: 5px;
}

.table-container .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" data-ng-app="usersApp">
  <div class="panel panel-default table-container">
    <div class="panel-heading">Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="usersCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group search-box">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search User" data-ng-model="search">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="dataTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Full name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Suite</th>
                <th>Zipcode</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users|filter:search">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td><a href="mailto:{{user.email}}">{{user.email}}</a></td>
                <td>{{user.address.city}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.street}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.suite}}</td>
                <td>{{user.address.zipcode}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But it does not work, for some reason I can't understand. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Update: working fiddle **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/34770/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
    $scope.users = root + "/users";
```

Here you have not made any http request to retrieve the data . Here the users variable in scope  is only a
 string i.e

```
 $scope.users =  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
```

The code should be something like this

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

// Create an Angular module named "usersApp"
var app = angular.module("usersApp", []);

// Create controller for the "usersApp" module

app.controller("usersCtrl", ["$scope","$http", function($scope,$http) {
  var url = root + "/users"
  // $http is a service in angular which is used to make REST calls
  // we call the url  and get the data , which is resolved as a promise
  $http.get(url)
 .then(function(data){
// after the data is resolved we set it in the scope
    $scope.users = data.data;
 })


}]);
```

Comment: I have fixed the minor bugs , Now it should work well enough

Comment: I am just learning Angular, so I appreciate any (hands-on)  help. Could you comment your code to make it explicit.? Thank you!

Comment: I have done a bit . But I reckon you should read a  little about $http . I assume you know about REST calls

Comment: I tried the same "recipe" with a JSON file stored locally (_data/users.json_) and `var url = "data/users.json"` but it does not work. I must be missing something.